# Working directory changing after fopen call with absolute path

Tags: c, fopen

I'm using `fopen` and `SDL_LoadBMP` to load files. The file paths come from command line arguments or hardcoded relative path strings. I've found that if I mix loading files from absolute and relative paths, I cannot load files from the relative paths because the working directory has changed.

In between calls to `fopen`/`SDL_LoadBMP`, I print the working directory:

```
TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, buffer);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

Initially, this prints the executable's directory:
`C:\path\to\executable`

If I load a file from a relative path (e.g. `files\file.txt`) the file loads and the directory stays the same.

If I load a file from an absolute path (e.g. `C:\path\to\executable\files\file.txt`), the file loads, but if I print the working directory again, I get the directory of the file: `C:\path\to\executable\files`. Then I can't load any files by the relative paths, since they are relative to the executable directory but `fopen` is searching in the files directory.

Why is the working directory changing? How can I mix absolute and relative paths with `fopen`?

Here is some sample code for my `SDL_LoadBMP` calls (cleaner example than my `fopen` calls, but the issue happens with both, and the SDL call is backed by `fopen`):

```
int load_surface(const char* source, SDL_Surface** surface)
{
    printf("Load image: %s\n", source);

    // Attempt to load the surface.
    *surface = SDL_LoadBMP(source);

    // Nothing loaded?
    if (!sdl_surface) {
        printf("Failed to load image\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Done loading image\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If I print the working directory before and after the above call, the working directory changes if I use an absolute path.

Comment: What is `MAX_PATH` defined as? I suspect your problem is elsewhere. `fopen()` doesn't change the path...

Comment: `MAX_PATH` is defined in the Windows API. I only use it for logging the current directory, I store the paths in other buffers.

Comment: Okay, so long as `MAX_PATH` is defined and sufficient (because the constant is generally `PATH_MAX` -- provided in `limits.h`)... I suspect you have some Stack-Smashing taking place. Neither `fopen()` or [GetCurrentDirectory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) alter the path. So long as you are using Win32, then `MAX_PATH` is `260`, see [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd)

Comment: I'm not using `MAX_PATH` for the actual calls to `fopen`, just the logging, and the issue happens even if I use static string literals for all the paths.

Comment: I'm still drawing a blank based on what you have posted. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way I can duplicate your results and enlist the aid of a compiler in narrowing down your issue.

Comment: Did you call GetOpenFileName or GetSaveFileName (or something else that brings up the OS open/save dialogs) by any chance?

Comment: You could try to go a little deeper... according to https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/5346cf842c00dbebeb07f1df09ac4fad5f368fa6/include/SDL_surface.h#L327 you could try, whether the change is initiated by `SDL_RWFromFile` or by `SDL_LoadBMP_RW`.